# How to use BLE in Maui?

Tags: c#, maui, maui-blazor

I have visual studio 17.2.0 preview installed with MAUI workload. How can I use bluetooth low energy apis on android and/or iOS?

Apparently Xamarin.Essentials cannot be installed into MAUI app.

Comment: Maui.Essentials is bundled with Maui. Intended to be same as Xamarin.Essentials, just a different namespace. Add `using Maui.Essentials;` to top of source file. There might be some APIs not yet implemented; I don't know if those are there yet.

Comment: also, I'm not aware that Essentials has any BLE apis so not sure how that's relevant

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/tree/main/src/Essentials/src).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I think it does not support BLE

Comment: @Shadow,  Did u try like " triaxis.BluetoothLE.Maui ", "InTheHand.BluetoothLE", "Shiny" Nuget packages for Bluetooth development?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Vanilla` version of [Plugin.BLE](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le) library.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/277): BLE ****is not on our roadmap** for .NET 6.** We are discussing bringing Essentials together with Forms in dotnet/maui as there's a growing overlap and interdependence.

If you want to use BLE, you may need to write platform-specific code, you can refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ri5nJsapOI) to know how to use  .NET MAUI  Dependency Injection.

Comment: Pretty poor show really. I mean bluetooth isn't exactly new tech. A lot of sports devices and peripherals use it!!! Is it just too hard for MS to understand? If so I get it. React Native can do it, so can flutter. 

Comment: Bluetooth and Gps are quite essential, I was hoping Maui would have solved it. I'm a little disappointed, because I still need to code native apps for android and ios

Comment: Is this sorted in 2023 or still this is not supported? This makes me feel MAUI is really not worth banking on.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this topic for a while. I know it is an older question, but let me answer this question for others.

**Please note, that I use this only for Android platform.**

I use this library for BLE transmitting, which is meant to be used in Xamarin, but works well in Maui with some adjustments.
[Android-beacon-library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library)

As you progress with writing your code, don't forget to make your transmitting method platform specific.

```
#IF ANDROID
your code...
#endif
```

If you are targeting devices with Android 12+ you will need to add this piece of code to the Application tag of your AndroidManifest.xml, because the library is not meant to use with Android 13... But this works as a workaround.

```
<receiver android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.StartupBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also don't forget to ask user for the right permissions, as they differ from Android 11 and lower.

For iBeacon scanning I use [Plugin.BLE](https://github.com/dotnet-bluetooth-le/dotnet-bluetooth-le) library.